# Find and replace regex in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, replace

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I am trying to find and replace a method call using the syntax below:

Find what:

```
  TakeAndCompareScreenshot(.*);
```

Replace with :

```
  TakeAndCompareScreenshot(.*); \n                                                                     
  Upgrade_CommonMethods.Errorfinder(driver);**
```

please help me to resolve this problem?

I need to just add `Upgrad_CommonMethods.Errorfinder(driver);` in below of all `TakeAndCompareScreenshot(.*);` line without any values changes

Is this possible? Either in Visual Studio 2013 or Notepad++?

[image: issue image]

Comment: In the replace with, don't re-use the `(.*)`, but instead use a capturing group: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17194010/736079. Also note that `(` and `)` are special characters in regex and need to be escaped in your search pattern using `\(` and `\)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the replace with, don't re-use the `(.*)`, but instead use a capturing group: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17194010/736079. Also note that `(` and `)` are special characters in regex and need to be escaped in your search pattern using `\(` and `\)`.

Search:

```
TakeAndCompareScreenshot\((.*)\);
```

Replace (`$0` contains the whole string captured by the search):

```
$0\n     Upgrade_CommonMethods.Errorfinder(driver);
```

Or (`$1` contains the contents of the first item between `(..)`):

```
TakeAndCompareScreenshot($1);\n    Upgrade_CommonMethods.Errorfinder(driver);
```

Comment: Hi jesse buddy,    thank you,  and its working with out fail,