# Is there a way to find all occurrences of using var with a require, and replacing just those results with const?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, is there a way to use a regular expression to find all statements which use `var` to declare a variable that assigns a value using `require`, and then replace just the `var` with `const`?

I have tried searching and I’m unable to find an answer.

This is the attempt at the regex (this part works): `var[ 0-9a-zA-Z]*= require`

It is the search and replace portion of just a part of the match where I am unsure how to do it, or if it is possible.

I’ve set up a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vscode-gyfgum).

In this screenshot, I’m trying to replace

```js
var zlib = require('zlib');
```

by

```js
const zlib = require('zlib');
```

[image: Screenshot showing my attempt at regex with search and replace.]

Comment: Look into the usage of capturing groups in VS Code.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks for your quick reply - it is about using the tool itself - i do not see why including an image of that caused a downvote. I did add a StackBlitz to make the question and problem more interactive. I appreciate the advice to look into capturing groups.

Comment: @WineGoddess please refer to the below answer for the explanation to your question. Please add the exact snippet in the question in text format along with the image as it is easier for others to review your snippet and work on it locally.

Comment: @WineGoddess i have added more description to the question as an suggested edit for the same

Comment: Thank you @Danny - i did include the code via StackBlitz - is that an acceptable way to share the behavior of the code and tool? I didn't know what to search for. The comment from SebastiaSimon was helpful - and your answer much more concise and clear than my regexp.

Comment: @WineGoddess i think it is but i am a newbie here as well. I think this is more of a meta discussion. Glad we could get this resolved.

Comment: @WineGoddess Questions and answers have to be self-contained, so everything we need to know to answer a question or to apply an answer has to be inside the post itself. Links and images may only be _supplementary_.

Comment: Find: `\bvar\b(?=.*\brequire\b)` replace : `const` See https://regex101.com/r/DvRKOB/1

Comment: See also https://regex101.com/r/ma8Elf/1  Capture groups are not needed in this case.  Use a positive lookahead instead - makes the replacement value simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
in find section: var(.*?)=(.*?)require\(
in replace section: const$1=$2require(
```

[image: Find and replace in action]

Using round brackets around regex (.*) allows it to become a group which can be referred in the replace section of vscode by using group number $1,$2 and so on

Please read [vscode documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#capture-groups-and-replacement-patterns) for detailed explanation

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24936071/855763) for another example.

Comment: Thank you! - the .* is cleaner and shorter as what I had as well.

Comment: Although, `.*` may match too much. I’d recommend `.*?` instead. I’d _also_ recommend, simply going through all `var`s and replacing them by `const` or `let` as needed.

Comment: @SebastianSimon updated the regex and screenshot based on your recommendation.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/TD0Aj3/1 for a couple of cases that should not be matched, like `const somevar = require('zlib');`  Word boundaries will help.